# How to count date difference in python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, datetime, datediff

I have a data frame named `table` which looks like below

```
       Date         ID
0   2015-12-30  2658789.0
1   2017-04-12  2658789.0
2   2014-06-23  2658789.0
3   2015-12-30  2658789.0
4   2016-01-06  2658789.0
5   2012-10-15  2658731.0
6   2011-04-14  2660120.0
7   2015-09-28  2660120.0
8   2017-02-10  2660120.0
9   2016-12-12  2660649.0
10  2017-05-03  2660649.0
11  2016-05-25  2660649.0
12  2015-09-28  2660649.0
13  2014-08-11  2660649.0
14  2016-01-22  2660649.0

print(table)
{'Date': {0: '2015-12-30', 1: '2017-04-12', 2: '2014-06-23', 3: '2015-12-30', 4: '2016-01-06', 5: '2012-10-15', 6: '2011-04-14', 7: '2015-09-28', 8: '2017-02-10', 9: '2016-12-12', 10: '2017-05-03', 11: '2016-05-25', 12: '2015-09-28', 13: '2014-08-11', 14: '2016-01-22'}, 'ID': {0: 2658789.0, 1: 2658789.0, 2: 2658789.0, 3: 2658789.0, 4: 2658789.0, 5: 2658731.0, 6: 2660120.0, 7: 2660120.0, 8: 2660120.0, 9: 2660649.0, 10: 2660649.0, 11: 2660649.0, 12: 2660649.0, 13: 2660649.0, 14: 2660649.0}}
```

The types of 2 columns in table

```
table.dtypes 
Date     object
ID      float64
dtype: object
```

I need to count the average of follow-up times for each ID. 
For each ID, follow-up times are defined as the time period (in days) between 
the latest date and the first date 
the second-latest date and the first date 
the third-latest date and the first date 
etc.

I wrote script for more simple situation (please see below), in which the follow up time is just the time period between the earliest and the latest date for each ID. The problem with my script is that as it iterated over rows, it took much time to run

```
# Group and get distinct Date by ID 
table = table['Date'].groupby(table['ID']).unique().reset_index()

# Get the latest and earliest Dates of each ID
from datetime import datetime
result = []
for index in range(len(table)):
    list_of_dates= [datetime.strptime(date,"%Y-%m-%d") for date in table.iloc[index,1]]
    n = table.iloc[index,0]
    x = max(list_of_dates)
    y = min(list_of_dates)
    result.append([n, x, y])
    df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=['ID', 'LatestDate', 'EarliestDate'])
    print(df)

# Count Follow-up time
df.loc[:,'LatestDate':'EarliestDate'] = df.loc[:,'LatestDate':'EarliestDate'].astype('datetime64[ns]')

df['FollowUpPeriod'] = (df['LatestDate'] - df['EarliestDate']).dt.days
df['FollowUpPeriod'].mean()
```

Could anyone help me with the **new situation** and in a **more efficient** way? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: You realize that the AVERAGE interval time is just the number of days between the very first and the very last, divided by the number of entries minus 1, right?

Comment: Thanks Tim!
Yup, that's the script I wrote for the old situation. I need help with the new situation which is based on multiple follow-up times, not just the number of days between the very first and the very last

Comment: Then I don't understand what you're asking.  You said you wanted the average time between entries.  That value would be `(last - first) / (N - 1)`.  If you compute `(A-B) + (B-C) + (C-D) + (D-E)`, they all cancel out.  It equals `A-E`.

Comment: Oops sorry for the mix-up. What I wanted would have been ((B-A) + (C-A) + (D-A) + (E-A)) / (N-1).  Thanks for picking up this error. I will edit my question shortly

Comment: Could you post the code to reproduce your table, please?

Comment: Hi Vitalizzare, I convert my table into a dictionary and add it to my question. Hope it helps reproduce my table. If you have better way to do this, please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Date': {0: '2015-12-30', 1: '2017-04-12', 2: '2014-06-23', 3: '2015-12-30', 4: '2016-01-06', 5: '2012-10-15', 6: '2011-04-14', 7: '2015-09-28', 8: '2017-02-10', 9: '2016-12-12', 10: '2017-05-03', 11: '2016-05-25', 12: '2015-09-28', 13: '2014-08-11', 14: '2016-01-22'}, 'ID': {0: 2658789.0, 1: 2658789.0, 2: 2658789.0, 3: 2658789.0, 4: 2658789.0, 5: 2658731.0, 6: 2660120.0, 7: 2660120.0, 8: 2660120.0, 9: 2660649.0, 10: 2660649.0, 11: 2660649.0, 12: 2660649.0, 13: 2660649.0, 14: 2660649.0}}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

(
    df
    .set_index('ID')
    .get('Date')
    .sort_values()
    .groupby(level=0)
    .apply(lambda s: (s.drop_duplicates().iloc[1:] - s.iloc[0]).mean())
    .fillna(pd.Timedelta(0))
)
```

Output:

```
ID
2658731.0      0 days 00:00:00
2658789.0    713 days 16:00:00
2660120.0   1878 days 12:00:00
2660649.0    689 days 00:00:00
Name: Date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Let's check it manually for ID = 2658789.0 to be sure we are on the right way:

```
df.query('ID==2658789')['Date'].drop_duplicates().sort_values()
```

```
2   2014-06-23
0   2015-12-30
4   2016-01-06
1   2017-04-12
```

So we have to calculate the mean of three differences:

```
(
  (2015-12-30 - 2014-06-23) 
+ (2016-01-06 - 2014-06-23)
+ (2017-04-12 - 2014-06-23)
) / 3 
= (555 days + 562 days + 1024 days)/3 
= 713.6(6) days    (0.66... days = 24 * 0.66... hours = 16 hours)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks heaps for your smart answer. Your code is very concise!

Comment: Thanks again for your updated version. It now produces the expected results.

Answer (score 1):

**Is this what you need?**

```
import io
import pandas as pd


data = """Date,ID
2015-12-30,2658789.0
2017-04-12,2658789.0
2014-06-23,2658789.0
2015-12-30,2658789.0
2016-01-06,2658789.0
2012-10-15,2658731.0
2011-04-14,2660120.0
2015-09-28,2660120.0
2017-02-10,2660120.0
2016-12-12,2660649.0
2017-05-03,2660649.0
2016-05-25,2660649.0
2015-09-28,2660649.0
2014-08-11,2660649.0
2016-01-22,2660649.0
"""


table = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data))
table.Date = pd.to_datetime(table.Date)
table = table.sort_values(by=['Date', 'ID'], ignore_index=True)


df = table.groupby('ID').Date.unique().reset_index()


df['avg'] = df.Date.map(lambda x: sum([d - x[0] for d in x[1:]]) / (len(x)-1) if len(x) > 1 else pd.Timedelta(0))


print(df.loc[:, ['ID', 'avg']])

          ID                avg
0  2658731.0    0 days 00:00:00
1  2658789.0  713 days 16:00:00
2  2660120.0 1878 days 12:00:00
3  2660649.0  689 days 00:00:00
```

---

```
[d - x[0] for d in x[1:]]
```

it creates a list with the differences with the first date,
then they are added and divided by the number of dates minus 1

Comment: Hi @josepn, thank you for your answer. Could you please explain more about your formula to calculate df['avg']? Your result is not similar to my expected result

Comment: @NguyenPham You're right, I misunderstood how to calculate times.
I have already corrected it.

Comment: Big thanks for your explanation. Your script runs well now.